# Error while installing psycopg2 using pip

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, pypi

I am trying to run docker in django using this command `docker build -t myimage .` Now the docker file tries to run the `RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir` but when ot gets to the   `Downloading psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)` section, it throws the error.

NOTE: i do not have psycopg2 in my requirements.txt file only the `psycopg2-binary`.

requirements.txt file

```
...
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.7
django-filter==21.1
django-formset-js-improved==0.5.0.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
psycopg2-binary
python-decouple==3.5
...
```

```
  Downloading pytz-2022.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 500.6/500.6 kB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 380.6/380.6 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-383i9hb2/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-383i9hb2/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-383i9hb2/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-383i9hb2/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-383i9hb2/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./my_app ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
# CMD ["gunicorn", "main_app.wsgi:application", "--bind"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Error%3A+pg_config+executable+not+found

Comment: Hey I've been try all those solution, but they are not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the system dependencies (pg_*) if you want to use psycopg2, otherwise, you can use the all-in-one package that include them by remplacing psycopg2 by psycopg2-binary

Comment: Where should I replace the pyscopg2 from, because I do not have it in my requirements.txt file???

Comment: i also had this issue, where is the place that `pyscopg2` would be replaced?